# Java - Get image file extension given its source and its mime type

Tags: java, image, file, mime-types, file-extension

Is there a way or a library in Java to get the extension of an image file given its source as a byte array and its Mime type?

I am asking this since the same mime type can be used for different extensions.

Comment: Well, then choose the extension you prefer.

Comment: Not all MIME types have a recommended file name extension.

Answer (score 3):

As other said, it's not 100% reliable, but I know [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) can do that.

You don't need the content if you already have the mime type:

```
MimeType type = MimeTypes.getDefaultMimeTypes().forName("image/png");
String extension = type.getExtension(); //.png
```